# #Order by Not Null using expression Extension linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, iqueryable

I have a custom IOrderedQueryable function as below.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> srcQuery, 
string orderColumn, bool isAscending)
{
  var type = typeof(T);
  var property = type.GetProperty(orderColumn);

  if (property == null)
    throw new Exception("Column property \"" + orderColumn + "\" does not exist on the type \"" + typeof(T).FullName + "\"");

  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
  var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
  var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
  MethodCallExpression resultExp = 
  Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),isAscending ? "OrderBy" : 
 "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, 
  srcQuery.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));

   return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)srcQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

I would like to know if there is anyway I could do a order by with the condition property!=null to display not null values first followed by the null values in the above orderByExp  expression

Comment: is this not possible to use in your case ? `OrderBy(x => x.property == null ? 0 : 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the property access to perform the equivalent of `query.OrderBy(x => x.property == null ? 0 : 1)`

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByNull<T>(IQueryable<T> srcQuery, string orderColumn, bool isAscending)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderColumn);

    if (property == null)
        throw new Exception("Column property \"" + orderColumn + "\" does not exist on the type \"" + typeof(T).FullName + "\"");

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.Condition(
        Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property), Expression.Constant(null, property.PropertyType)),
        Expression.Constant(1),
        Expression.Constant(0));

    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    MethodCallExpression resultExp =Expression.Call( typeof(Queryable), isAscending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { type,  typeof(int) },
    srcQuery.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));

    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)srcQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

Note: If the property is not nullable (for example `int?` or `double?`) an error will occur,

**Edit**:

The above  version of this only works for nullable properties. Another version would be to order by a default value for nullable columns and to do normal ordering for all others aka: `if (property is nullable) query.OrderBy(x => x.property == null ? default(basePropertyType) : x.property) else query.OrderBy(x => x.property)`

The version for that would look like this:

```
static Dictionary<Type, object> DefaultTypeValues = new Dictionary<Type, object>
{
    { typeof(string), "" },
   // { typeof(DateTime?), new DateTime(1753,1,1) } // Min date for sql date 
      { typeof(DateTime?), new DateTime(9999,12,31} // Max date for sql date 
};

public static object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
{
    object defaultValue;
    if(!DefaultTypeValues.TryGetValue(t, out defaultValue))
    {
        if(t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(t.GetGenericArguments().Single());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Could not get default value for type " + t.FullName + " consider adding it in DefaultTypeValues");
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(IQueryable<T> srcQuery, string orderColumn, bool isAscending)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderColumn);

    if (property == null)
        throw new Exception("Column property \"" + orderColumn + "\" does not exist on the type \"" + typeof(T).FullName + "\"");

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    // default sort is performed by o=> o.Prop
    Expression propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var propType = property.PropertyType;

    // If property is nullable we add teh null check 
    if (propType == typeof(string) || (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        var defaultValue = GetDefaultValue(propType);
        // If the property is nullable we sort by (o => o.Prop == null ? default(propType) : o.Prop)
        propertyAccess = Expression.Condition(
            Expression.Equal(propertyAccess, Expression.Constant(null, propType)),
            Expression.Constant(defaultValue, propType),
            propertyAccess
        );
    }

    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), isAscending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { type, propType },
    srcQuery.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));

    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)srcQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

The default value is customizable by type in the DefaultTypeValues or if no value is specified it will default to the underlying nullable type (ex for `int?` it will be 0)

Comment: Hi Titian Thanks for your reply. The field that i have currently is Nullable date time. Will the above work for the same too?

Comment: Should work for any `Nullable`, I just tested with `DateTime?` and the query was generated corectly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the final version of my code. Made a small change should work, but I can't test right now because I am in bed. If it doesn't work let me know and I will find a solution tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Titian Thanks a lot for your reply. I just tried to debug the code and the previous error i had mentioned was working fine. But now i get another error stating that {"Argument types do not match"}. This happens when i have a non-nullable property-> {System.DateTime CreateDate}

Comment: @rockingmeister Ok, but the question becomes what do you want it to do in this case .. Since the initial request was to sort by weather it is null or not. If the column is DateTime it cannot be null.. so what sorting should it do ?

Comment: Yes , the issue is, i use the same helper method for both nullable and non nullable types. Probably i would do an if condition to just allow non-nullable types to access the above mentioned  var propertyAccess. You think that it would be a good idea?. Thanks a lot for all your help. Saved me much time.

Comment: Ok, I will provide a version that works with both shortly in about 30 minutes, when I get to a pc

Comment: @rockingmeister just to make sure I understand what you want this to do. `if (property is nullable) query.OrderBy(x => x.property == null ? 0 : 1) else query.OrderBy(x => x.property)`.  This would mean that for nullable properties it would only order by weather it was null, not by the content of the column.

Comment: @rockingmeister Maybe a better approach would be `if (property is nullable) query.OrderBy(x => x.property == null ? default(basePropertyType) : x.property) else query.OrderBy(x => x.property)`. When I say default(basePropertyType) I mean for `int?` I would use `0`

Comment: the second approach is exactly what i am trying to implement

Comment: @rockingmeister Added the new version, I tested it and it appears to work.

Comment: Works Like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :-)